# convert negative decimal number into HEX and HEX into decimal

Tags: decimal, hex

Am trying to understand the convertion between decimal and hexadecimal!
according to this tool [decimal to hexadecimal converter](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/decimal-to-hex-converter)---------------------------------> -130 is FFFFFFFFFFFFFF7E !!
I would like to understand how we calculate it and how we calculate the convertion from hexadecimal to decimal too!

Any help would be great appreciated! Thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they are using some sort of "complementary notation" to represent negative base 10 numbers as hex (base 16) numbers.

So -1 sound be represented as FFFFFFFFFFFFFFE, and -16 FFFFFFFFFFFFFFEF (though the tool froze for me when I tried certain powers of 16).

( it'd be like representing them as 9999999999999998 and 9999999999999983 in base 10 ).

That convention aside, you'll have to read about base representation of number systems to understand the general case.  Think about the analogy of a car's odometer.  In base 2 (binary) it "turns over" at '2', so 1=1, 2=10, 3=11, 4=100, and so on.  '100' in base two implies 1x2^2 + 0x2^1 + 0x2^0, or 4 + 0 + 0, or 0.

For base 10, which you are used to, digits "turn over" at powers of 10 instead of powers of 2.
...,98,99, 100,..., is the same sequence as 9x10^1 + 8*10^0, 9x10^1+9x10^0, 1x10^2 + 0x10^1+0x10^0.

To represent a given number in whatever base you choose, the digit (starting from left to right) represents a multiple of the base to that power.

For Hex, the '1's spot (1,2,...,C,D,E,F) is 1 through 15, and then when you hit 16 to the first power it turns over to being represented as '10', or 1x16^1 + 0x16^0.  the '16s' spot now has a 1.  100 in hex would have 1 in the '256s' (or 16^2) spot instead of the 1s, 10s, 100s you are used to in decimal base 10.

To covert back to base 10, multiple out by powers of 16.  So CCD1 would be 12*16^3 + 12*16^2 + 13*16^1+ 1*16^0.